# Ошибка при сборке Could NOT find Boost (missing: system)

Tags: c++, windows, bootstrap, cmake, boost

При попытке собрать проект выдает ошибку, хотя все установленно вроде как корректно
Windows 10
MinGW

```
cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" .. && cmake --build . --target execute

CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find Boost (missing: system) (found suitable version "1.68.0",
  minimum required is "1.68.0")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:594 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2345 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  app/CMakeLists.txt:22 (find_package)
```

папка с бустом
[image: буст]

```
SET(PROJECT execute)

set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS        ON)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED      ON)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME     OFF)
SET(SOURCE main.cpp)
find_package(Boost 1.68.0 REQUIRED system)
add_executable(${PROJECT} ${SOURCE})
if(Boost_FOUND)
    include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
endif()
if(MINGW)
    target_link_libraries(${PROJECT} PUBLIC ws2_32)
    target_link_libraries(${PROJECT} PUBLIC wsock32)
endif()
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT} PUBLIC ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT} PUBLIC ${LIB_CONSTRAINT_GENERATOR})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT} PUBLIC ${AUTONESTER_LIB})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT} PUBLIC ${LIB_NESTING})
target_compile_features(${PROJECT} PRIVATE cxx_std_17)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а CMake вкурсе, где лежит Ваш буст?

Comment: @KoVadim вкурсе, path прописан, переменные тоже проставил. Добавил скрин в вопрос

Comment: Попробуйте в окружении добавить переменную BOOST_ROOT равную C:\boost_1_68_0.

Comment: @KoVadim не помогло, ровно та же ошибка

Comment: я попробовал воспроизвести Вашу ситуацию. Правда никаких переменных в окружение не добавлял. Просто запустил cmake-gui .. с build каталога, заполнил Boost_INCLUDE_DIR (я воспользовался кнопочкой справа), нажал Configure и Generate и все ок... Но потом я попробовал сделать как то попроще. И я просто сделал так `cmake -DBoost_INCLUDE_DIR=C:\boost_1_68_0 ..` и все отработало. Вторым этапом запустил `cmake --build .` и все собралось. Правда я запустил через консоль "x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2019 Preview".

Comment: @KoVadim, сделал как вы написали, не помогло, ошибка та же. проект коммерческий его уже год никто не пересобирал и ничего нового не дописывал, я бы рад скинуть больше информации но не могу, из условий: boost > 1.68, mingw-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0 компилятор обязательно и под винду все это собрать

Comment: @KoVadim при том я повторил всю сборку которая лежит на сервере, все path-ы так же прописал, и он не собирается, тут говорят год назад была похожая проблема cmake ругался и не видел буст, но как это решили никто не помнит

Comment: может буст собран не тем компилятором? например, студийным. Я бы попробовал сделать как я - взять этот CMakeLists.txt, добавить main.cpp который содержит helloworld и пробовать по разному, в том числе студийным компилятором

Comment: @KoVadim снес msvс чтобы избежать проблем, 
`b2 toolset=gcc link=shared architecture=x86 address-model=64 --build-type=complete` собирал вот так, все нормально собралось, закрепил с boost debug скрин

Comment: Похоже, что Вы существенно продвинулись. Boost уже находит, компилирует, но пока не проходит линковка.

Comment: @KoVadim только вот почему, все пути указаны, пробовал указывать их через set в cmake, билдить статически\динамически и тд и тп, все равно не линкует, в чем может быть причина

Comment: я бы попробовал закомментировать вот эту строку `set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS        ON)` и собрать приложение ещё раз. а  там будет смотреть, как дальше

Comment: @KoVadim закомментировал, ошибка та же undefind reference boost:: ..., разрешили попробовать через msvc собрать, буду пробовать

Comment: ок, похоже проблема где то ещё рядом - очень часто не находит либы потому что либо битность (32/64) не совпадает, либо .... они просто отсутствуют.